# Powershell Script Help (Get-Process and send output via SMTP)

Tags: windows, powershell, service, scripting, smtp

I'm trying to make e `Powershell` script to check a specific service(name) with `Status` and `StartType` and additional information like time and date of the servers and server names.

List of servers from .txt is only the FQDN's.

I have the desired output in powershell but can't get it properly to send via SMTP.
In one case it doesn't show the state or won't show to processes only the names of the servers and all the information is plain text not in containers for the different servers.

Desired output :[desired output in powershell need to transfer to smtp email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7GWl.png)

```
$ServerList = Get-Content -Path "C:\new_folder\servers.txt"
Foreach ($server in $ServerList){
$time = "---"
$time = ([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $server).LocalDateTime)
$server + ', ' + $time
Get-Service -ComputerName "$server" | where-object {$_.name -like '*goge*'} | Select @{Name="server";Expression={$server}},Name,DisplayName,StartType,Status
}send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -Priority high
```

Comment: You don't save your results to variable, how you want sent it then(you still can sent it to pipe)? `Send-mailmessage` outside your loop and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this little fix, i leave comments

```
    $ServerList = Get-Content -Path "C:\new_folder\servers.txt"
    $array=@() #array which will contain result get-service
    Foreach ($server in $ServerList){
    $time = "---"
    $time = ([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $server).LocalDateTime)
    $server + ', ' + $time
    #add to our array result of each get-service from servers
    $array+=Get-Service -ComputerName "$server" | where-object {$_.name -like '*goge*'} | Select @{Name="server";Expression={$server}},Name,DisplayName,StartType,Status
    }
    send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $array -BodyAsHtml -Priority high
```

Comment: Hello Vad, thanks but this solution doesn't work. I tried it now as you described. It gives error in the body of the send-mailmessage and if I run it without the Send-MailMessage commands I get output only the FQDNS and current time in the terminal.